# how to convert dom4j xml into Swing Jtree?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I am using dom4j to parse xml. Then I want to be able to represent this xml as a Jtree. Whenever I programmatically add or remove nodes through dom4j, I want the changes to be reflected immediately in the Jtree. When I click on a Jtree node, how do I catch the event?

I've discovered the dom4j.swing package at http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

However, I don't know how I would go about using that. Which I should use, I am not sure. I can't seem to find any examples or tutorials on this area.

BranchTreeNode, DocumentTreeModel, LeafTreeNode.

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;

public class Foo {

    public Document createDocument() {
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element root = document.addElement( "root" );

        Element author1 = root.addElement( "author" )
            .addAttribute( "name", "James" )
            .addAttribute( "location", "UK" )
            .addText( "James Strachan" );

        Element author2 = root.addElement( "author" )
            .addAttribute( "name", "Bob" )
            .addAttribute( "location", "US" )
            .addText( "Bob McWhirter" );

        return document;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/dom4j/samples/swing/JTreeDemo.html, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It's explained on that site in the bottom when you expand the process method